# Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-rootscope, angularjs-apply

I just tried to use `'ngTagsInput'` in my angular app and the tags in the app are running fine,but sumultaneously its throwing the error in the console.Its not affecting my UI flow but yes errors are logging in the console.Why the cause and solution for this error.
Error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply......
```

this is order how my files are getting downloaded for browser

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.6/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-animate.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularjs-toaster/0.4.4/toaster.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-datatables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/loading-bar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/timer.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.7/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/angular-dragdrop/src/angular-dragdrop.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/ng-tags-input/ng-tags-input.js"></script>
```

and my view

```
<tags-input ng-model="email_details.cc"></tags-input>
```

my controller

```
$scope.emailTemplates=[{
    'id'        :1,
    'cc'        :['developer@earning.com','a@rning.com'],
    'bcc'       :['ak@learning.com'],
    'subject'   :'1testing common template testing common template ' ,
    'created_on':'2015-07-04 16:04:02',
    'body'      :'body<b>hi'

},{
    'id'        :2,
    'cc'        :['cc2@rning.com','cc2@email.com'],
    'bcc'       :['bcc@email.com','bcc2@email.com'],
    'subject'   :'2testing common template testing common template ' ,
    'created_on':'2015-07-04 16:04:02',
    'body'      :'<p>a</p>'

}
]
```

There are the self defined directives where in i am using scope.watch/.eval/.apply

```
    .directive("myDatepicker", function () {
      return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
          var updateModel = function (dateText) {
            scope.$apply(function () {
              ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(dateText);
            });
          };
          var options = {
            dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
            onSelect: function (dateText) {
              updateModel(dateText);
            }
          };
          elem.datepicker(options);
        }
      }
    });
.directive("ngRandomClass", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            ngClasses: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attr) {            

            //Add random background class to selected element
            elem.addClass(scope.ngClasses[Math.floor(Math.random() * (scope.ngClasses.length))]);
        }
    }
})
.directive('compile', function($compile) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(
      function(scope) {
        return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
      },
      function(value) {
        var result = element.html(value);
        //console.log(scope.$parent);
        $compile(element.contents())(scope.$parent.$parent);
      }
    );
  };
})
```

Comment: Please, post your code so people could help you find an issue. It is difficult to do with just an error message. Also it would be great if you could reproduce the problem on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and share it.

Comment: i had just injected a new dependency and i found an error if i use it as an html attribute

Comment: Did you add ngTagsInput to your index.html file? Did you add it to your app.js? Have you any alerts present? Sometime these cause digest errors.

Comment: @MichaelRadionov i have updated my codes now.Hope that might help you.

Comment: Are you calling scope.apply() or scope.digest() manually?

Comment: @BobDoleForPresident No no where.

Comment: is it because any of my upper loading js file effecting tagsInput or getting some clashes ?or i need to change the order of the downloading js fie

Comment: @BobDoleForPresident sorry but yes i am using scope.$apply() check my updated question

Comment: Try writing the apply() function like this: function () {              ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(dateText);
  scope.$apply();
            };

Comment: I guess it's because there is a code (not Angular project) somewhere that changes browser's cookies when Angular tries to change that too. So, a collision occurs.